# Toto TSU99A.X toilet fill valve settings for (old) MS854 1.6gpf toilet

Tags: plumbing, toilet, plumbing-fixture

I need to replace a leaky fill valve in my 20+ year old Toto toilet. I called Toto tech support and they helped me identify the toilet as an [MS854](https://www.totousa.com/ultimate-one-piece-toilet-16-gpf-elongated-bowl). I bought the the fill valve replacement TUS99A.X that was recommended in the [parts sheet](https://www.totousa.com/filemanager_uploads/product_assets/PartsManual/PD-00345_MS854114.pdf).

The instructions provide the chart below to set the fill height and refill ratio. But my toilet model MS854 is nowhere to be found on this chart! I double-checked that this is the recommended fill valve.

So... what settings should I use for my toilet?

I've started Googling every model number in the chart, and so far they all seem to be 1.28gpf models, so maybe there's a legal requirement for new float valve documentation to only have settings for newer, water-saving models? If true, then how can I figure out the settings I need for my older model?

[image]